# Pass parameter from HTML to javascript function in LWC condition inside iterator without child component

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any workaround or way to make this work in LWC without creating child component

//I know below code will not work in LWC, so I'm looking for way to make below llogic in LWC //without creating child component

```
HTML:

<template iterator:it={myList} >
<template if:true={it == 'table'}>
</template>

JS:
checkTableValue(event){
return event.target.value == 'table'; 
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pass in parameters to an iterator value. Further, you can't use "expressions" as you would in Aura anyways.

If you don't want/need a child component, you need to put the data to evaluate into the list:

```
<template iterator:it={myList}>
  <template if:true={it.value.isTable}>
  </template>
</template>
```

...

```
this.myList[index].isTable = true;
```

Comment: Do you know which approach is better from performance perspective : child component vs add boolean property?

Comment: @3202User The Boolean property is technically more performant... but for all practical cases, it shouldn't matter.